# Protocol declared in Objective-C Framework is not visible in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

As the title says I have trouble using a protocol declared in Objective-C framework in a Swift app. I will try to describe the situation in detail below.

I have a framework that has mixed Objective-C and Swift code.

This is similar to what I have in the file with protocol definition.

```
// MyLibrary.h

@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>;

@interface ClassThatUsesMyDelegate
@property (weak, nonatomic, nullable) id<MyDelegate>delegate;
@end

@protocol MyDelegate
- (void)aMethod;
@end
```

Objective-C code is wrapped in a module as such:

```
// module.modulemap

module MyObjCLibrary {
    header "MyLibrary.h"
    export *
}
```

Then I have Swift code that uses the Objective-C code via `import MyObjCLibrary` where all of the declared above in `MyLibrary.h` is visible and usable.

The umbrella header of the framework has `#import "MyLibrary.h"`. Which should expose all the code from `MyLibrary.h` to anyone who uses my framework.

**Here is where the problem starts.** When I embed this framework in my test app I can use any Swift code from my library as well as `ClassThatUsesMyDelegate` from `MyLibrary.h`. Howerver, when I try to use the protocol `MyDelegate` I get a compiler error that this type has not been declared. Example of usage below:

```
// MyViewController.swift

import UIKit
import MyFramework

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

extension MyViewController: MyDelegate { // Error: Use of undeclared type 'MyDelegate'
    func aMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This seems to be the case only with protocols, everything else like varibles, classes, enums etc are accessible.

Comment: You said "I can use any Swift code from my library as well as ...". Are you saying that your framework has both Objective-C and Swift code? Or are you saying that you have an Objective-C framework, and you're using that framework in a Swift project?

Comment: @Rob: I have both Objective-C and Swift code in my framework. And the framework is used from Swift app.

Comment: @Rob: framework can be written in both obj-c and swift code. Similar to how it can be achieved with bridging header in coding apps apps. But in case of frameworks modulemap should be used as bridging header is unavailable. Example of this you can see here: [Github](https://github.com/danieleggert/mixed-swift-objc-framework)

Comment: I guess so. I had faint recollection that frameworks didn't support dual language targets, but they clearly now do. Sadly, I couldn't get that demo you referenced to work at all on Xcode 8.3.3, but seems to work without any custom `modulemap` at all. See https://github.com/robertmryan/ObjcSwiftFrameworkDemo. I can't reproduce your problem. If you're still having a problem, maybe you can create MCVE and share it with us.